# .NET Core on Linux: Allow writing to a named pipe by another user

Tags: linux, .net-core, named-pipes

Using `NamedPipeServerStream` to read and `NamedPipeClientStream` to write data, everything works fine when both processes are run by the same user, but if I run the client process by a different user I get `Permission denied /tmp/CoreFxPipe_my_pipe`. The pipe "file" indeed doesn't have write permissions for other users.

`PipeOptions` has a member `CurrentUserOnly`, but I didn't set it (I even tried setting `None` explicitly). How can I allow other users to write to the pipe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `/tmp` directory has the [sticky bit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sticky_bit#Usage) set by default, meaning other users can't write unless permission is explicitly granted.

Unfortunately the file used by `NamedPipeServerStream` can't be placed elsewhere, so we have to set the applicable permissions ourselves with [SetUnixFileMode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.setunixfilemode?view=net-8.0).

```cs
const string pipeName = "my_pipe";
NamedPipeServerStream pipe = new(pipeName, PipeDirection.In /* other args */);

if (Environment.OSVersion.Platform == PlatformID.Unix)
{
    System.IO.File.SetUnixFileMode(
        $"/tmp/CoreFxPipe_{pipeName}",
        System.IO.UnixFileMode.OtherWrite);
}

pipe.WaitForConnection();
```

If your client also needs to read, include the `System.IO.UnixFileMode.OtherRead` mode.